# Bubble Sort vs Shuttle Sort

Tags: algorithms, sorting

When sorting a list of items, shuttle sort (the one taught in the A-Level Maths unit D1 by OCR, NOT Cocktail sort - see below) does no more than as many comparisons as [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (they always do equal swaps, which is due to the nature of these algorithms). I wanted to know whether or not bubble sort could ever sort a list with fewer comparisons than shuttle sort.

I attempted to write a computer program to do it, but after getting both sorting algorithms to work but not an auto run through of inputs lists, I had to manually enter them...

The Shuttle sort I'm referring to is described as follows (laid out how the exam board lays it out):

**1st pass:** Compare the 1st and 2nd numbers in the list and swap if needed

**2nd pass:** Compare the 2nd and 3rd numbers in the list and swap if needed. If swapped, compare 1st and 2nd and swap if needed.

**3rd pass:** Compare 3rd and 4th number in the list and swap if needed. If swapped, compare 2nd and 3rd, swap if needed. If swapped, compare 1st and 2nd, swap if needed.

This process continues throughout the entire list.

Comment: Why not just randomly generate input lists and keep sorting them while keeping track of the number of comparisons?

Comment: Try sorting `19 20 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18`.

Comment: Okay, after running it for a while, it generated 127000 different lists of length between 7 and 27. Every single time the shuttle sort had less than or equal to the number of bubble sort comparisons. In reply to Henning, they both have 54 comparisons?

Comment: @Stewart: That's strange. How does shuttlesort make do with so few?

Comment: @Henning: I'm not sure, I just tried a similar pattern by-hand with just 5 numbers and they both make 9 comparisons. They both make 3 wasteful comparisons and 6 swaps!

Comment: @Stewart: I would expect shuttlesort needs to use about twenty steps moving to the right (taking the 20 up), then about twenty wasted moving to the left, then about twenty moving to the left (taking the 19 up), and finally about twenty more moving to the left and checking that there's nothing more to do.

Comment: @Henning: Ah, now I see your problem. The shuttle sort I'm referring to is the one I mentioned in my original question: the one taught in D1 a-level maths. You're referring to the cocktail sort I think? Either way i just ran a test of 1,000,000 different lists and 999,014 resulted in shuttle sort being less while 986 resulted in shuttle sort being equal to the bubble sort.

Comment: "A-Level D1" may mean something within the particular institution you're studying at (which we don't know what is), but is is useless as a reference for the remaining 99.9999% of humanity. You should provide a proper reference to the algorithm you're talking about, not just the name of a course in an undisclosed institution that teaches it.

Comment: I will edit my original question to show this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you referring to the method (shuttle sort) where we use bubble sort on the first $2$ elements then on the first $3$ elements and so on?

Comment: @Winther: see original question now, but yes, i think so.

Comment: Then shuttle sort will always require fewer (or equal) number of comparisons than bubble sort since when we include one more number to our list the list is already sorted so we can stop comparing when we reach a number equal or smaller than then one that is added. The number of swaps should be the same though if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Okay, that seems to agree with my testing I coded. Could you write that up as an answer please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the largest element in it's right place we need do perform $n-1$ comparisons so the total number of comparisons of a bubble sort is

$$B_n = n-1 + n-2 + \ldots + 2 + 1 = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$$

Shuttle sort does a bubble sort on the first two elements, then on the first three elements and so on. When we are sorting in the $(k+1)$'th element $a_{k+1}$ we know that the first $k$ elements are already sorted so we can stop comparing elements when we hit an element that is equal to or smaller than $a_{k+1}$. This means that we only need at most one full pass through the list each time we add in another element giving us

$$S_n \leq 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n-1 = B_n$$

The number of swaps will be the same in both cases.